# Angular - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get') at EmployeeComponent.onOnSearch

Tags: angular

In Angular-14 project, I am given an external API to consume (3rd party). I tested it on POSTMAN, and it works fine.

Then external API is secured with three (3) headers:

The third party API is secured with these headers:

headers:

```
"headerId": "hdd22", 
"headerName": "hdd44", 
"headerPw": "hdd66"
```

The given api is as shown below:

> https://thirtpartyapi.com/EmployeeRecord?employeeCode

employeeCode is the parameter for the API.

When the correct employeeCode is given as parameter, I have this resulted:

```
{
    "EmployeeCode": "KKT001",
    "EmployeeName": "AGBOR PTOLEMY",
    "Department": "AGBOR PTOLEMY"
}
```

component.ts:

```
  onSearch() {
    if (this.codeValue.length === 6) {
      let headers = new HttpHeaders({
       'headerId': 'hdd22', 
       'headerName': 'hdd44', 
       'headerPw': 'hdd66'
      });
      this.http.get(
        `https://thirtpartyapi.com/EmployeeRecord?${this.codeValue}`,
        {
          headers: headers
        }).subscribe(
        (response: any) => {
          console.log(response); 
        },
        (error: any) => {},
      );
    }
  }
```

component.html:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="employeeCode">Employee Code<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
  <input
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    formControlName='employeeCode'
    id="employeeCoder"
    (input)="onSearch()"
    placeholder="employeeCode">
</div>

<label for="employeeName"></label>
```

employeeCode is 6 characters.

What I want to achieve is that when user enters the employeeCode into the text input, as soon as it's 6 characters, the employeeName of that particular employeeCode parameter should be displayed on the label employeeName.

However, I got this error:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')     at EmployeeComponent.onOnSearch

How do I resolve this and achieve my goal?

Thanks

Comment: The codeValue property is not linked to the search input formControlName. Why you set the condition to be equal to a length of 6 chars while the property you check is not connected to the html input field ?

Comment: @onrails - I set to 6 chars so that when  the characters in the text input gets to  6  chars, it searches and displays the employee name on the label.What doI do?

Comment: have you injected angular's `HttpClient` as `this.http`?

Comment: @ChrisGilardi -- Yes, I have done thy

Comment: maybe you could post more of the code in that component TS file